# Outlook 2007 / 10 & 13 ignoring Conditional CSS

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, conditional-statements

I am designing a responsive email. It currently works in every client within Litmus apart from Outlook 07/10/13 (the infamous word rendering engine versions). In order to have my email display correctly in other versions of Outlook (earlier and later) I use:

```css
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style>
    .leftCol {
         width:350 !important;
        margin-left:4 !important;
}
    .rightCol {
        padding:0 !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

It works perfectly. However, Outlook 07/10/13 just doesn't seem to take notice of these conditonals. Strangely, if I manually edit the inline css for the associated tables (leftCol & rightCol) it works; however, I can't do this because it will then wreck all my other client renders.

Is there anything I can do to get conditional CSS working in Outlook 07/10/13?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely, conditional stuff like that gets stripped out. You could try ensuring its INSIDE the body tag - stuff outside that will get stripped out by some email clients.

Comment: This is what I suspected. How would I bring CSS styles inline with conditonal statements? Something like:

<table style="color: green; <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> width: 350; <![endif]-->">

??

Comment: Conditional can't be done inline I don't think. Your best bet is always keeping email templates dead simple - it's such a hacky and inconsistent thing to develop for, that you just gotta make sure things fail gracefully, and accept certain constraints. If it won't work in header, and won't work in the body, it probably won't work at all (e.g. that client is stripping out IE conditionals).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in exactly what part isnt working (e.g. width doesnt change from percent to defined, etc) or provide more of the code for us to work on debugging? I have a couple ideas, but without more info, it is too broad for me to give a good answer. Also, you cannot do inline conditional CSS for MSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditionals aren't the problem: you need to add `px` to your values (ex: `width:350px;`). Outlook is picky.